# Is there any framework that can render Swing/AWT code into a webapp?

Tags: java, swing, legacy

I am looking for a way to use a legacy Swing/AWT java code base remotely. 
I know that a lot of web frameworks like GWT use concepts very similar to the layoutmanagers in Swing.

Is there anything out there that goes the full way and implements Swing or AWT by producing a webapp with HTML/Javascript?
So basically I would like to switch the highest level javax.swing.JFrame to newframework.JFrame like vncj does it similarly for VNC.

Comment: I'm with @MK as this offers what is likely the safest way to display your app with little to no need to modify the original code.

Comment: Idea is to run the application on a device with limited performance. That is why Citrix is probably not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a simple google search i came up with [this](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/index.html) software, no personal experiences with it tough.